# replaceWith() method's sizeToScene property cuts top and increases bottom part of the window

Tags: tornadofx

I have 2 views: LoginScreen and MainScreen. I use `replaceWith()` to switch to the MainScreen. They both have the same `prefHeight` and `prefWidth`. The problem is  that when I go from LoginScreen to MainScreen, the bottom part of the window snaps and gets bigger for like 30-40px.

This was my code:

`loginScreen.replaceWith(mainScreen, sizeToScene = true, transition=metroAnimation)`

and then I tried it with `sizeToScene=false` and it worked, no more snapping... however I noticed another problem, around 30-40px of MainScreen's top was gone:

`sizeToScene=true` with growing bottom:
[image]

`sizeToScene=false`, bottom doesn't grow but top part is eaten:
[image]

How can I fix it, is there something that I am doing wrong?

This is my MainScreen:

```
class MainScreen : View("MainScreen") {

private val toolbarLayout: ToolbarLayout by inject()

override val root = borderpane {
    addClass(screen)
    top = toolbarLayout.root
    center = flowpane {
        vgap = 20.0
        hgap = 20.0
        paddingAll = 20
        for (i in 0..14) {
            add(MobileAppGridItemLayout(i))
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is my `ToolbarLayout`

```
class ToolbarLayout : View() {
override val root = borderpane {
    addClass(PanelStyle.toolbar)
    paddingAll = 20

    left {
        hbox(20) {
            label("MainView") {
                addClass(PanelStyle.titleText)
                textFill = Color.WHITE
            }
        }
    }

    right {
        vbox {
            button("Logout") {
                addClass(toolbarButton)
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

This is a style for default screen height and width used in both LoginScreen and MainScreen:

```
screen {
        prefHeight = 720.px
        prefWidth = 1280.px
}
```

Edited:
I tried `replaceWith()` without animation and here are the results:

1. When `sizeToScene=false`, no growing bottoms and no eaten tops.
2. When `sizeToScene=true`, bottom grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue, it was because items of `flowpane` were more than they could fit into the window. I added `flawpane` into the `scrollpane` and the problem was solved.

```
override val root = borderpane {
    addClass(screen)
    top = toolbarLayout.root
    center = scrollpane {
        isFitToHeight = true
        isFitToWidth = true
        vbarPolicy = ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED
        content = flowpane {
            vgap = 20.0
            hgap = 20.0
            padding = insets(20, 40, 20, 40)
            for (i in 0..15) {
                add(MobileAppGridItemLayout(i))
            }
        }
    }
}
```